# Directive não está sendo chamada, validador customizado AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives

Tenho a seguinte diretiva:

```
.directive('validateCPF', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

            ctrl.$validators.cpf = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                console.log('chamou directiva');
                var validatorCPF = new CPF();
                return (validatorCPF.valida(viewValue));
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Eessa diretiva usa uma lib externa para validar o `cpf`, porém não chega nem ao `console.log`.

Meu form:

```
<input id="cpf" class="col-xs-12 cpf" type="text" name="cpf" ng-model="cau.cpf" validate-CPF >
```

> Versão AngularJS 1.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você possui alguns erros na declaração da sua diretiva. A diretiva do `AngularJS` é aplicada através da diferenciação entre letras maiúsculas e minúsculas, sendo que ela para cada letra maiúscula que você definir no `.directive` ela deverá ser minúscula e precedida de um hífen em seu `HTML`. Veja o exemplo:

```
//No angular
.directive('minhaDiretivaAqui', function () {

//E no seu html
<input minha-diretiva-aqui ...
```

Lembrando que você não deve iniciar o nome do `.directive` com letra maiúscula.

---

Para a sua diretiva funcionar, você deve declarar assim:

```
//AngularJS
.directive(validateCpf)

//No html
<input validate-cpf
```

Do modo que você declarou, você teria que chamar ela deste modo:

```
<input validate-c-p-f
```

---

Complementar à validação, você pode chamar a função somente após o usuário preencher o valor do CPF através do `ng-blur`, assim quando o usuário terminar de digitar o CPF, ele chama a função e faz a verificação. Veja:

```
<input id="cpf" class="col-xs-12 cpf" type="text" name="cpf" ng-model="cau.cpf" validate-cpf ng-blur="verificaCpf(cau.cpf)">


//Na diretiva - Coloque a sua verificação dentro de uma função
scope.verificaCpf = function(valorCpf) {
    //Sua verificação aqui
    ctrl.$validators.cpf = ...
};
```

Comment: gostei da ideia do blur, porem vou validar na funcao na diretiva se o viewModel é definido. nesse caso so após perder o foco, da mesma forma que acontecia com o blur...

Comment: A sim, a seu critério. Apenas mencionei como alternativa. =D